# Can a Pearl of Power be used to cast Identify?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

My group recently located a [Pearl of Power](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/pearl-of-power) on their adventures.

The campaign setting is not always a place where spell components are easy to come by. As a consequence, the players have asked me if they can use the Pearl of Power as a spell component in order to cast [Identify](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/identify).

Identify requires 'a pearl worth at least 100 gp' (which will not be consumed). The Pearl of Power does not have a stated value but it might reasonably be concluded to be worth consderably more than 100 gp due to it's other properties.

Can it be used in this way?

Comment: You ask should you allow it, but I'm finding it hard to follow why you wouldn't. Is there a reason you are keeping components scarce? And would allowing the Pearl violate that? Further, are you just some for advice here (should you do it) or are you asking about the rules?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Definitely about rules. Advice would be offtopic. It could possibly be argued that a Pearl of Power is not the same thing as a pearl in game terms. Or, that as it has no stated value, even if it it considered a pearl, it's not eligible for use here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Yes, it can, for both RAW and RAF reasons.

It is worth at least 100 GP based on being an *uncommon* magic item which is valued at 101-500 GP (DMG, p. 129 & p. 139).  It is a pearl.  The spell component is not consumed in the casting.

> (a pearl worth at least 100 gp) (*identify*, spell description, SRD)

**RAW (rules as written):** nothing prohibits its use.
**[RAF<sup>1</sup>](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=2) (rules as fun):** why not allow it?  That's a good use of assets by the players.
Bravo to your players!

---

<sup>1</sup> 
<sub>RAF. Regardless of what’s on the page or what the designers intended, D&D is meant to be fun, and the DM is the ringmaster at each game table. The best DMs shape the game on the fly to bring the most delight to their players. Such DMs aim for RAF, “rules as fun.” ... I recommend a healthy mix of RAW, RAI, and RAF!</sub>

Comment: The DMG specifically says *"The D&D rules help you and the other players have a good time, but the rules aren't in charge"* Something like that has been in D&D all the way back to the first edition - in 1976, Gygax himself wrote *"as with any set of rules [...] these are for your playing enjoyment. If you find sections which do not bring you enjoyment, alter, expand or delete them as you see fit"*. So, you could argue that Rules As Fun *are* Rules As Intended, and indeed, Rules As Written!

Comment: @Anaximander While I agree, I probably should not digress into that style point in this answer; I added in the RAF point/link in support of players being rewarded for getting the most out of what they have. (And because I don't think RAF gets as much love as I wish it would ...)