# Can an unidentified pearl be used as a component for the Identify spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, spellcasting, spell-components

On our adventures we found a magic pearl that was appraised at least 300gp. We suspect it's a *pearl of power*. It's a two parter question:

1. Can an unidentified (magic) pearl (thats worth more than 100gp) be used as component for the *[Identify](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/identify)* spell?
2. If yes, can you use that pearl to identify itself using the Identify spell?

Comment: At least related: [Can a Pearl of Power be used to cast Identify?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/136240)

Comment: Also, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Keep in mind of course that your DM holds the real answer to this question. We can help a DM or a player interpret rules, bits of Forgotten Realms (et al.) lore, and so on, but if your DM rules that in your campaign's setting the magic of a Pearl of Power interferes with the magic of Identity etc., then that overrules anything that some random Internet strangers say.

Answer (score 17):

### Yes, the Pearl of Power (unidentified) is a qualifying pearl

From the magic item's text:

> While this ***pearl*** is on your person, ...

If it's worth 300 gp, it's worth at least 100 gp. It is a pearl, it's worth enough, it's good to use. Just because the pearl may have additional magic imbued within it, doesn't disqualify it from the fact that it is a pearl.

### You're still missing something, though

Spell also requires an Owl Feather of indeterminant value.

Available in a Spell Component Pouch or replaced by a Spellcasting Focus.

### Yes, you can identify the pearl using itself

From the text of Identify:

> You choose one object that you must touch throughout the casting of the spell. ...

Other than being a requirement for casting, the spell identify makes no additional restrictions on its spell components. The pearl being used as a material component can be held as part of the casting and thus will qualify for both being available for use as a component for the cast *and* the touched target of the spell.

### However, your mileage may vary

In most campaigns, a pearl of power would not have a value associated with it, being a magic item. Most major tier items lack a price due to the way magic items are intended to be balanced within 5e.

One could argue that this pricelessness of magic items makes them definitely worth 100 gp. Others will argue that them not having a listed price means they can't qualify as their true price is indeterminant.

The only reason the answers to the above are yes is that in *your* campaign, it is worth 300 gp.

Comment: The DMG values uncommon magic items (like the pearl of power) at 101-500 gp, so it definitely qualifies.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov "***If*** your campaign allows for trade in magic items, rarity can also help you set prices for them." - DMG p135. It's not exactly a given in every campaign.

Comment: @Axoren it's *worth* is in that range even if camping doesn't allow you to *buy* it for the money.

Comment: @Mołot At this point, it's mostly semantics, if you can't sell it for that price, then it's not really worth that price. The setting of the price is what gives it that intrinsic worth, and ultimately without it you can't really argue it's worth anything at all. The argument that the DMG's optional pricing is in effect even when it's not used by the campaign is a rather odd one, and ultimately one I don't expect every DM to agree to.

Comment: This is case is "If we were playing in a campaign where Magic Items were priced, it would be worth X." which Is very different from the case for other equipment where they are assigned intrinsic worth regardless of if you can buy them. "Airships are worth 20,000 gp in the DMG, but you can't buy one in this campaign." By the same token, this would make Airships also indeterminant in value, from a practical perspective, but they are specifically assigned this value rather than recommended a price that the DM can set for them if they so choose to assign value to them.

Comment: I don't think I understand.  Even in games where PC's may not _buy_ magic items, they can still _sell_ them, can't they?  Why wouldn't the value of a magic item be what it could be sold for, even if none were available to PC's for purchase?  If the PC's acquire an item which they cannot use (for class restrictions) or do not want to use (for attunement slots), is that item simply worthless to them?

Comment: @Kirt If a pearl is intrinsically worthless (system values it at 0 gp), but you convince a merchant to buy it for 100 gp, can that merchant cast identify? This kind of question has been asked elsewhere on the site. Paying 100 gp for something doesn't make it worth 100 gp.

Answer (score 9):

### Yes, it can

All that the spell requires is a pearl worth at least 100 gp. It does not care if the pearl is magical or not, just that it has the required value. You can use it to identify itself, as it is not consumed.

Comment: @Carcer is right. "Consumed by default" was a 3.x thing and 5e changed it.